# What is a good cloud storage to use in a simple .net program?

Tags: visual-c++, dropbox

My friends and I have a little Minecraft server and I'm in charge. As you may know, in order for a client connect to a Minecraft server, it must have the same mods the server has. It is a bit of a pain to keep my friends clients in sync with the server, because everytime I update a mod in the server I have to share it with all my friends via skype.

I'm new to programming and I would like to code a little application to share with my friends that would be used to download mods from a web file storage. I tried using dropbox but it is not as simple as I thought. Here's the core of my code:

```
array<bool>^ Downloader::DownloadAll(TextWriter^ output)
{
array<bool>^ result = gcnew array<bool>(_download_instructions->Count);

try
{

    WebClient^ webclient = gcnew WebClient();


    for (int i = 0; i < _download_instructions->Count; ++i)
    {
        SourceDestinationPair^ download_instruction = _download_instructions[i];

        output->WriteLine(L"\nDownloading: " + download_instruction->Source);
        array<unsigned char>^ webdata = webclient->DownloadData(download_instruction->Source);

        output->WriteLine(L"Writing: " + download_instruction->Destination);
        File::WriteAllBytes(download_instruction->Destination, webdata);

        result[i] = true;
    }

    output->WriteLine(L"\nAll downloads complete");
}
catch (Exception^ e)
{
    output->WriteLine(L"An error has occured: " + e->Message);
}

return result;
```

}

When I run this trying to download a 3MB file it only downloads 128k. I'm guessing dropbox links are for that page where you get the "Download" button, and not for the file itself. I looked it up and it seems I would need to download and add a reference to a third party dll, but I would like to make it as simple as possible, since I'm just an amateur programmer. Is there another file storage on the web that is simpler to use? Or maybe a way to use dropbox that doesn't require me to download and learn a lib? All I want is that code of mine to work as long as I change the url to something else. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

All I have to do to make my code actually download the file is to change the end of the dropbox link from "?dl=0" to "?dl=1".

Comment: This is probably right (but hard to tell without seeing the actual URL being used). See https://www.dropbox.com/help/201 for details.

Answer (score 0):

I created a Amazon Web Service EC2 windows virtual machine, where i'm hosting a wamp server to allow outside connection. I managed to connect to it after opening up certain ports etc. Planning on creating a nice fontend and connecting it to a domain in the near future as well, should be a nice solution for your needs as well

Everything needed for playing around with and hosting a small site is free, worth looking at...

http://aws.amazon.com/